# Считывание групп чисел, отличных от нуля на php

Tags: php

Считывать количество групп элементов отличных от нуля.
Т.е. изолировать их от нулей, например
в A =[00011100110000000010000011]
делить на 
[111],
[11],
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oLwj.jpg),
[11]
И затем считывать группы, их должно быть 4, тогда A=4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметка: количество единиц как "одна группа" может быть более четырех, например:
01111111100000111000111111100001000 и здесь должно выйти число 4

Comment: Простейший конечный автомат прекрасно подойдет.

Comment: а это что - массив, строка?

Comment: @splash58 Ну откуда же он знает :) Он даже не догадывается, что такое число в десятичной системе счисления великовато. Значит либо это числа в двоичной системе счисления, о чем он "умалчивает" в задаче. Либо строка (она же по сути тоже частный случай массива). Ему задана задача, а он даже и не пытался ее решить. Запостил как есть - с картинками. Но здесь не решают домашние задания.

Comment: @MaxZS вопрос то всё равно интересный )

Comment: @Naumov да в каком же месте он интересный-то? Конечный автомат простейший нужен.

Comment: Или просто `count(preg_split('/0+/',$str,0,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))`, если по условиям кроме 0 и 1 ничего быть не может

Comment: @Mike Я бы заминусовал за такой ответ....

Comment: @Naumov Это не особо дольше будет,чем `$cnt=0; $last=0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++) {
 if(!$last && $str[$i]) $cnt++; $last=$str[$i];
}
`

Comment: @Mike да от куда у вас такие решения беруться? по крайней мере тут можно обойтись таким вот образом `$str = str_replace(0,'',$str); $res = strlen($str);` где `$res` сумма 1, но не думаю что это правильный вариант. В задаче подсовывают бинарные данные не просто так.

Comment: @Naumov Только ваш вариант посчитает количество 1, а надо количество групп 1. т.е. '111' подряд - это только 1, а не 3.

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php) возвращает количество совпадений с шаблоном. Тогда задача решается так:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    1 => '001110001011101100001001111000',
    2 => '110011100101000111111111111000',
    3 => '011111111111111111111111110001',
);
echo "Id\tCount\n";
foreach ($arr as $id => $bin) {
    echo $id . "\t" . preg_match_all('/1+/', $bin) . "\n";
}
```

или без регэкспов:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    1 => '001110001011101100001001111000',
    2 => '110011100101000111111111111000',
    3 => '011111111111111111111111110001',
);
echo "Id\tCount\n";
foreach ($arr as $id => $bin) {
    $count = 0;
    $prevDigit = 0;
    foreach (str_split($bin) as $digit) {
        if ($digit && !$prevDigit) $count++;
        $prevDigit = $digit;
    }
    echo $id . "\t" . $count . "\n";
}
```

и, по просьбе трудящихся, с использованием смекалки:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    1 => 0b001110001011101100001001111000,
    2 => 0b110011100101000111111111111000,
    3 => 0b011111111111111111111111110001,
);
echo "Id\tCount\n";
foreach ($arr as $id => $bin) {
    $count = 0;
    $tmp = ($bin & ~$bin >> 1);
    while ($tmp) {
        $count += 1;
        $tmp = $tmp & ($tmp - 1);
    }   
    echo $id . "\t" . $count . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Обожаю минусы без комментариев

Comment: так это задание на проверку математического мышления и смекалки а не на умение юзать regexp и foreach...

Comment: Почему вы так решили? В вопросе этого нет.

Comment: @Naumov третий вариант вам больше нравится?